# How do i flash the bios for my acer e1 531 because the screen is black

Tags: laptop

I tried downloading software from acer driver support but the files included do not match the files i saw in a youtube tutorial on how to do it, the youtube tutorial had .rom .flash files which were bootable...but the latest files i found was just one single file and i finding it hard to boot it form a flash drive...what am i doing wrong...i have no access to windows 8 because the screen is black and this is the last option im trying after several other checks i saw on youtube...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can **not** boot the laptop with anything ("*the screen is black*"), a dvd (Windows setup, Linux live), or even just get into BIOS/UEFI, then it might have some hardware problem (i.e. be really broken) and no downloaded file could fix it.

Why is "*the screen is black*", did you already try flashing the BIOS/UEFI? Or did something else happen to the laptop? I'd try some hardware troubleshooting, if you really can't boot anything (even just BIOS/UEFI).

If you can boot the laptop, and it's just Windows that isn't working, then I'm not sure if updating the BIOS/UEFI would help, but these sites should have some tips:

- [Accessing the UEFI (BIOS) setup on a Windows 8 system](http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27102/%7E/accessing-the-uefi-) This article only applies to: systems with Windows 8 pre-installed
- [How do I enter the BIOS/UEFI Setup Utility on my notebook computer?](http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/34243) This article only applies to: Notebooks and Netbooks
- http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1646850/acer-aspire-531-uefi-update.html
- http://community.acer.com/t5/Notebooks-Netbooks/acer-aspire-e1-531-bios-recovery/td-p/225316
- [Changing BIOS Versions when Upgrading to Windows 8](http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/26979) -

  > Should I change the BIOS to UEFI before upgrading to Windows 8?
  >
  > Acer does not recommend or support changing the BIOS to UEFI when upgrading to Windows 8. Legacy BIOS provides support for Windows 8, so it is not necessary to upgrade the BIOS. Acer does not support changing from standard BIOS to UEFI or vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

Flashing the BIOS/UEFI settings can result in OS problems and requiring it to be reinstalled.
Check the BIOS/UEFI settings and set your hard-drive to the mode it originally was (Legacy, SATA or RAID or UEFI-SATA/RAID). This could be a difference that causes the OS not to boot.

Comment: Can you by chance be more specific about what problems you are talking about because the only problems I am aware of can easily be solved by restoring a setting after it was changed to its default. Certainly does not require the reinstallation of the operating system.

Comment: Reinstallation is required when changing permanently from UEFI to BIOS-compatible. Also, UEFI newer versions can limit boot options elections. Some of them for example did disable/removed RAID mode on certain UEFIs. Since they are modular in nature, those features can be re-added, but its a more complex process which requires reflashing the UEFI with custom module installed (this is offtopic). What was important to mention is that the primary cause of such a failure is the wrong drive access mode (IDE/SATA/RAID).

Comment: You mean switching from MBR to GPT thus allowing you to use EFI firmware?  Its actually pretty simple to avoid reinstalling your operating system in a case like that.

Comment: Converting Windows BIOS installation to UEFI is a relatively complex procedure which is also likely to render the recovery partition unusable; I would not personally recommend this instead of a reinstall. If you want to do the opposite (GPT to MBR) its even worse.